# Custom ITaskHost on non windows system

Tags: msbuild, hook, target

I'm trying to register a custom `ITaskHost` in a `HostServices` to be accessed during the build process with the `Task.HostObject` Property.

```cs
HostServices hostServices = new HostServices();
string prjPath = "/mnt/devel/CrowIDE/build/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/src/CustomCrowIDE.targets"       
hostServices.RegisterHostObject(prjPath, "CustomBeforeBuild", "HookTask", this);
ProjectInstance pi = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.GetProjectInstanceForBuild (project);         
BuildRequestData request = new BuildRequestData (pi, new string[] { target }, hostServices);            
BuildResult result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build (solution.buildParams, request);
```

But the `HostObjet` property of my custom task stays null.

I've read that ITaskHost are com object on windows that have to be registered in the ROT table, but here on linux, is it possible to bypass this constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution to forward result to the hosting application using the `ILogger` and the possibility to raise custom events with `CustomBuildEventArgs`.
The trick is to use reflexion in the logger to bypass isolation.